# Pyo3: Why isn't an error thrown when using an incorrect constructor?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I am writing a python library with a Rust backend using pyo3 and I don't understand why there isn't an error thrown when you call the wrong constructor, I think what I'm saying will make more sense when I show the code.

```rust
// vector.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
pub struct Vector {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    x: f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    y: f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    z: f64
}

#[pymethods]
impl Vector {

    #[new]
    fn new() -> Self {
        Vector {
            x: 0.0,
            y: 0.0,
            z: 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
// lib.rs

mod core;

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use crate::core::vector::Vector;

#[pymodule]
fn imagine(_py: Python<'_>, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Vector>()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

It compiles fine but when I use the wrong constructor it doesn't raise any errors.

```py
>>> from imagine import *
>>> a = Vector("yo")
>>> a
<Vector object at 0x10eb5e650>
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in pyo3, if the method has 0 arguments, it doesn't check them. If you add at least 1 argument to `new`, it will check them the way you'd expect.

Comment: alright, thank you diego!